# Solving this differential equation using method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

We have the following differential equation:
$$u_xx-2u_xy+u_yy+9u_x+9u_y-9u=0$$
The goal is to solve with the method of characteristics, in other words to simplify, to give the canonical form. But I am not sure how to solve it.

Here is my thoughts:

1. Write down the characteristic equations.
2. Solve the characteristic equations.
3. Use the solutions to rewrite the original PDE in canonical form.

For 1, here is my attempt $\frac{dx}{dt}=1,\quad\frac{dy}{dt}=-2,\quad\frac{du}{dt}=9$, but I am not entirely sure and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: A first simplification is to rewrite the PDE as $$(x-2y+9)u_x+(y+9)u_y=9u.$$Now redo step 1.

Comment: @Gonçalo Sure, I got $\frac{dx}{dt}=x-2y+9$, $\frac{dy}{dt}=y+9$ and $\frac{du}{dt}=9u$. Solving, I get $x(t)=e^t(C_1-2C_2)-9$, $e^t(C_2-9)-9$, $\begin{aligned}u(t)=e^{9t}C_3.\end{aligned}$ Is this correct? How do I proceed further?

Comment: I think I got lost, could you help in writing a solution by any chance so I could learn how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the PDE
$$
(x-2y+9)u_x+(y+9)u_y=9u \tag{1}
$$
using the method of characteristics, we first write the [Lagrange-Charpit equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) in its parametrization invariant form:
$$
\frac{dx}{x-2y+9}=\frac{dy}{y+9}=\frac{du}{9u}. \tag{2}
$$
The solution of
$$
\frac{dy}{y+9}=\frac{du}{9u} \tag{3}
$$
yields
$$
u=C_1(y+9)^9. \tag{4}
$$
The solution of
$$
\frac{dx}{x-2y+9}=\frac{dy}{y+9} \tag{5}
$$
is slightly more complicated. Let's first rewrite it in terms of the variable $z=y+9$:
$$
\frac{dx}{x-2z+27}=\frac{dz}{z}\implies \frac{dx}{dz}-\frac{x}{z}=\frac{27}{z}-2. \tag{6}
$$
Dividing both sides of $(6)$ by $z$ we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{z}\frac{dx}{dz}-\frac{x}{z^2}=\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{x}{z}\right)=
\frac{27}{z^2}-\frac{2}{z}
$$
$$
\implies \frac{x}{z}=-\frac{27}{z}-2\ln|z|+C_2
\implies \frac{x+27}{y+9}+2\ln|y+9|=C_2, \tag{7}
$$
where we replaced $z$ with $y+9$ in the last equation. Combining $(4)$ and $(7)$ we finally obtain the general solution to $(1)$:
$$
u(x,y)=(y+9)^9F\left(\frac{x+27}{y+9}+2\ln|y+9|\right), \tag{8}
$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.

Comment: Thank you for the help.